# Simple HTML DOM parsing not working

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to extract emails, names and phone numbers from my html table and use these details in order to send an automatic email reply.

For some reason, I get a fatal error saying: `Call to undefined function file_get_html() in http://itecdigital.org.uk/2015/430926/BeautyFactoryBooking/admin.php on line 3`

My code for the html Dom parser:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_html('http://itecdigital.org.uk/2015/430926/BeautyFactoryBooking/admin.php');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
//Loop through each row
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    //Loop through each child (cell) of the row
    foreach ($row->children() as $cell) {
        echo $cell->plaintext; // Display the contents of each cell - this is the value you want to extract
    }
}

?>
```

Can anyone see whats wrong with this?

My html code for the table is as follows:

```
<?php

        echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email Address</th><th>Phone Num</th><th>Treatment</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Message</th><th>Reply</th></tr>";

        class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
            function __construct($it) {
                parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
            }

            function current() {
                return "<td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
            }

            function beginChildren() {
                echo "<tr>";
            }

            function endChildren() {
                echo "</tr>" . "\n";
            }
        }

        $servername = "#";
        $username = "#";
        $password = "#";
        $dbname = "#";

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql: host=$servername; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Booking_request_form.id_booking, Client_Information.first_name, Client_Information.last_name, Client_Information.email_address, Client_Information.phone_number, Booking_request_form.treatment, Booking_request_form.date, Booking_request_form.time, Booking_request_form.message FROM Booking_request_form INNER JOIN Client_Information WHERE Client_Information.id_client=Booking_request_form.client_fk"); 

            $stmt->execute();

            // set the resulting array to associative
            $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
                echo $v;
            }
        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $conn = null;
        echo "</table>";

?>
```

Is there an easy fix to this?

Comment: `file_get_contents` perhaps???????

Comment: @Dagon That just throws so much more errors. :/

Comment: file_get_html is not a core php functions, so unless you write your own ..

Comment: @Filip You have invalid HTML. That's why you receive warnings when you try to load the HTML as XML. For instance, you have never closed the tag `<div class="headertext">` which should be closed before `</header>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix [*Simple HTML Dom*](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) third part class commands (as per your question title) with [*DOMDocument*](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) built-in class commands, so your code can't work.

`file_get_html()` is a *Simple HTML Dom* function, replace it with `file_get_contents()`:

```
$html = file_get_contents( '/Users/sam/Downloads/trash.html' );

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors( 1 );      // <-- add this line to avoid DOM errors
$dom->loadHTML( $html );

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

Now, init an array (`$rows`) to fill with cells values and a integer string (`$cols`) for column numbers; your HTML is malformed and this variable will help you to produce a well-formed table:

```
$rows = array();
$cols = 0;
```

In your code there is another error: you put `<tr>` in `$elements`, then you refer it in `foreach()` using `$rows`. Then, you call `->children()` method to iterate through all children, but *DOMElement* don't have this method, use `->childNodes` property instead. But, first to all, check the row column number and update previously declared variable `$cols`. Inside nested `foreach()`, you add cells values to `$rows`. You will display later. To retrieve values of *DOMNode* use `->nodeValue` instead of `->plaintext`. I have wrapped `$cell->nodeValue` by `trim()` to remove extra spaces at begin/end of string:

```
foreach ($elements as $key => $row)
{
    if( $row->childNodes->length > $cols ) $cols = $row->childNodes->length;
    foreach( $row->childNodes as $cell )
    {
        $rows[$key][] = trim( $cell->nodeValue );
    }
}
```

Now, you have the cells values in multidimensional array `$rows`.

---

**Table display**

*Your* code for displaying table is not your code, it is a copy-and-paste from the [net](https://www.google.com/search?q=class+TableRows+extends+RecursiveIteratorIterator): it has nothing to do with your question and you can ignore it.

Use a simply code like this instead:

```
echo "<table>\n";
echo "    <tr>\n";
for( $j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++ ) echo "        <th>{$rows[0][$j]}</th>\n";
echo "    </tr>\n";
for( $i = 1; $i < count($rows); $i++ )
{
    echo "    <tr>\n";
    for( $j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++ )
    {
        if( isset( $rows[$i][$j] ) ) echo "        <td>{$rows[$i][$j]}</td>\n";
        else                         echo "        <td></td>\n";
    }
    echo "    </tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

This is only a working example, modify HTML code as you prefer. You can also change the order of cells. Note the different code between printing table header and printing table rows (`for()` loop start from 1). Also note the use of `$cols`: if a cell is empty, we output an empty `<td>`.

Comment: How would I then go on to displaying and extracting this information to use in my mail() function?

Comment: This must be a different question. Mark this question as answered and start new one. BTW, consider that your data is in `$rows` array. You can use [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) (see example #4) or [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function instead of `file_get_html`. There is no such function `file_get_html` in PHP.

However, there are few errors in the HTML:

1. Unclosed tag `<div class="headertext">`. I suppose it should have close tag right after `<a href="log_out.php">Logout</a>`;
2. Entities like `&` should be encoded as `&amp;`;
3. It could be considered as a bug but PHP doesn't recognise `header` tag and throw a warning. However, it could still load the HTML page successfully.
4. Last but not least, there are a number of mistakes of using `DOMElement` attributes.

I have rewritten your code to show you how it could work:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://itecdigital.org.uk/2015/430926/BeautyFactoryBooking/admin.php')

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$result = $dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_NOERROR);
var_dump($result);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
//Loop through each row
var_dump($elements);
foreach ($elements as $row) {
    //Loop through each child (cell) of the row
    foreach ($row->childNodes as $cell) {
        echo $cell->nodeValue; // Display the contents of each cell - this is the value you want to extract
    }
}


?>
```

and the HTML should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge" />
      <title>Beauty Factory Bookings</title>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   </head>
   <body>
      <img action="login_success.php" src="http://i.imgur.com/wbhPNAs.png" style="width: 240px; height:35px;"> 
      <header>
         <div class="headertext"> <a href="booking.php">Book Appointment</a> <a href="about.php">About Us</a> <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a> <a href="log_out.php">Logout</a></div>
      </header>
      <table style='border: solid 1px black;'>
         <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Phone Num</th>
            <th>Treatment</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Reply</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>1</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>Filip</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>Grebowski</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>grebowskifilip@gmail.com</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>07449474894</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>Waxing - Full Leg &amp; Bikini</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>11/03/2016</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>10:20</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>Is this okay?</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>2</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>Filip</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>Grebowski</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>grebowskifilip@gmail.com</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>07449474894</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>Anti-Age Facial</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>01/01/1970</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>10:20</td>
            <td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>Is this ok????</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
   <style> table { margin-top: 60px; border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 60px; } tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #f2f2f2 } th, td { padding: 15px; } img { padding-top: 12px; padding-left: 12px; } .headertext { float: right; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 3%; } body { background: url('#') no-repeat fixed center center; background-size: cover; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; } header { background: black; -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; filter: alpha(opacity=80); -moz-opacity: 0.8; -khtml-opacity: 0.8; opacity: 0.7; height: 60px; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; } a:link { font-size: 15px; margin-left: 75px; color: white; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none; } a:visited { font-size: 15px; margin-left: 75px; color: white; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none; } a:hover { font-size: 15px; margin-left: 75px; color: #C0C0C0; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none; } </style>
</html>
```

Comment: It throws 4 errors: 1) DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in entity. 2) DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: header and div in entity. 3) DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity. 4) Invalid argument supplied foreach().

Comment: @Filip You have invalid HTML. That's why you receive warnings when you try to load the HTML as XML. For instance, you have never closed the tag <div class="headertext"> which should be closed before </header>

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should have a proper HTML structure, not just the table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
        /* etc */
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, make sure to correctly close tags in the PHP output.

---

***EDIT***

I just researched Simple HTML DOM.

Make sure to include the library file in your code: `include("/path/to/simple_html_dom.php");`

Furthermore, for the Simple HTML DOM, you don't need to load `$html` to a DOMDocument. Simply say

```
$html = file_get_html('http://itecdigital.org.uk/2015/430926/BeautyFactoryBooking/admin.php');

$elements = $html->find('tr');
```

Please read the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual for more information.